# App store & Play Store approval guidelines for mobile-web wrapped apps

Tags: mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-website, mobile-application

Building mobile-web wrapped iOS & Android apps using Ionic framework. The apps might have some custom work included w.r.to user experience but otherwise pages/screens and navigation will more or less resemble the desktop web. Not sure if this will be treated as hybrid app?

Are are there any specific guidelines to be aware of to avoid app store / plat store rejections?

Additionally; can someone share some best examples of mobile-web wrapped apps where user experience is more or less similar to desktop web?

Comment: So if you just "wrap" mobile website - why do you need app store? what are the benefits for your efforts to get there? if its ability to leverage certain APIs that are not available on the web - use that as your focal area and during development you should emphasis this aspect. Apple would reject the app if all it is - is a converted mobile web. But they would accept it if it "makes sense" and has broad audience

Comment: Main reasons; wanna test the app market potential for a long time ecommerce Service, avoid investing too much time-effort-money by taking native app route

Comment: Then I would suggest you analyze which part of your desktop web is highly relevant to your user when they are on mobile and build out initial MVP around that part

Comment: That’s already considered and given that I need help with my original question